# Your app is currently live, but requires review before it's available to the public

Tags: facebook

I have problem with set status for my app to public. I have finished all review steps, but still i can't make it public. Here is screenshot from my review page:

[app status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xzdz.png)

Thank you in advance for answer

Comment: Facebook related issue. Off-topic.

Comment: It shows "App Center" in the Products list - if you have anything configured regarding App Center, then you might need to submit that for review, too.

Comment: Question about developping for Facebook could be on-topic (see the tag description), however it's true that this question is clearly aimed at their support, despite the fact it's about about developping a Facebook app.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns Facebook support directly, and is not code-related.